# keep docker image as binaries in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

since I am new to devops I need some clear guidance to make my effort worth.

I just need to packge  deployed service in kurbenets cluster using helm. Lets assume docker images are in private registry at the moment. What  I am inteted is to run helm chat in differnt kubenate cluster with out keeping referene to previouly descriped private docker registry.

So what I am planning is to  to keep docker images it self as binaries in helm chart rather than keeping reference to private docker registry.

Would it ever be possible? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store any docker images in the Helm charts. This is out of scope of helm's original design. The question was discussed in the Helm github: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2812

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Helm charts is package of kubernetes manifests only. You can't store docker images in them. You can only reference an image that is present in an registry. What you can do is to template your manifests such that the registry from which the images are referenced can be overridden using helm values. Then you can push the images from your private registry to any registry which is accessible from the installation location and then use this new registry while installing the chart.

```
$ cat deployment.yaml
image: "{{ .Values.images.registry }}/myimage:mytag
```

```
$ cat values.yaml
images:
  registry: example.com/default-registry
```